# message display function upon login not executed PHP

Tags: php, forms, function

I am trying to display a message if wrong username or password upon login, so I created to functions set_message and display message as following:

```
function set_message(){
if (!empty($msg)) {
    $_SESSION['message'] =  $msg;

}else 
    $msg = "";
}


function message_display(){

    if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }

}
```

I called set message function here:

```
function login_user(){

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $username = escape_string( $_POST['username']);
   $password = escape_string($_POST['password']);
     global $connection;
     $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND   password  = '{$password}'  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm($result);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        set_message("Username or Password Are Wrong!");
        message_display();
        redirect('login.php');
    }else{
        set_message("WELCOM ADMIN");

        redirect('admin');
    }
}
```

I called display message function in login.php file inside form:

```
<form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php login_user(); ?>
        <h3><?php  message_display();  ?></h3>

            <div class="form-group"><label for="">
                username<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"></label>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group"><label for="password">
                Password<input type="text" name="password" class="form-control"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
            </div>
        </form>
```

PROBLEM IS UPON WRONG USER/PASS REDIRECT SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED BUT WITHOUT MESSAGE DISPLAY

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

You never call `message_display()` here:

```
}else{
    set_message("WELCOM ADMIN");

     redirect('admin');
)
```

But you immediately do a redirect (assuming that function is working) so the message would never get displayed unless this is a SPA.